# Transforming Limits of a Double Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I´m working on trasnforming a double integral: $\int_0^\infty \int_0^x e^{-(x+y)} \,dy\,dx$ using the following identities identities. I need to get the limit to be 0 and1  in order to integrate it by using Monte Carlo´s integration

> $$\theta=\int_0^\infty g(x)\,\mathrm dx,$$ we could apply the substitution $y=1/(x+1),\mathrm dy=-\mathrm dx/(x+1)^2=-y^2\mathrm dx,$ to obtain the identity $$\theta=\int_0^1h(y)\,\mathrm dy,$$ where #1 $$h(y)=\dfrac{g\left(\tfrac1y-1\right)}{y^2}.$$

and #2 $$h(y)=g(a+(b-a)y)(b-a).$$

when

> $$\theta=\int_a^b g(x)\,\mathrm dx,$$
>   So far this is what I´ve done:

applying  #1 $h(y)$:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x \dfrac{e^{-((1/y) -1)+y}}{y^2} \,dy\,dx$$

and now applying #2 :

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dfrac{e^{-((1/yx) -1)+xy}}{(xy)^2}(x) \,dy\,dx$$
taking $a=0$ and $b=x$

Can anyone help to check my answers?

Edit: I found a hint reading several books, but I still can´t transform both limits to 0 and 1.

[image]

I should use the function above equate the integralto one in which both terms go from 0 to ∞.]
Thank you very much

Comment: You cannot substitute $y=1/(1+x)$ into a formula already containing $y$ as an independent variable from $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. What would be the correct substitution?

Comment: Why not first do the y-integral and then the x-integral? That is straightforward.

Comment: So I should use first $h(y)=(a+(b-a)y)(b-a)$ with the y´s on the first integral?

Comment: @PabloEstrada No.  Don't use $\bf y$ as the substitution variable.  Either simply integrate as is, or substitute $u=x+y$, then integrate.  See my answer below for both methods.

Comment: Hi! The reason I want to transform the limits is to use Monte Carlo´s integration. From what I´ve read I need to have the integral with limits 0 and 1 in order to get a correct answer from the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After serveral attempts I was able to solve this problem:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't need substitutions to solve this.

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \! \int_0^x e^{-(x+y)}\operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x
 & = \int_0^\infty\!\int_0^x e^{-x}e^{-y}\operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x
\\[1ex]
& = \int_0^\infty e^{-x}\left(\int_0^x e^{-y}\operatorname{d}y\right)\operatorname{d}x
\\[1ex]
& = \ldots 
\end{align}$$
Now use: $$\displaystyle\int_0^{\color{blue} w} a\,e^{b\,{\color{blue} z}} \operatorname{d}{\color{blue} z} = \frac a b (e^{b\,{\color{blue} w}}-1) $$

---

Although if you really wanted to use substitutions, to practice maybe, you could use: $$\begin{align}u&=(x+y)\\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} &= 1\\ y\in[0,x] &\to u\in[x,2x]\end{align}$$
Thus:
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \! \int_0^x e^{-(x+y)}\operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x
 & = \int_0^\infty\!\int_{x}^{2x} e^{-u} \operatorname{d}u\operatorname{d}x
\\[2ex] & = \ldots
\end{align}$$
And just integrate from there on.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your wonderful answer. The reason I want the limits to be 0 and 1 is because I want to integrate using Monte Carlo´s methods. On the book I´m reading the identities that I mentioned above are given to transform the limits. May be that´s something I should add to the question. Thanks again :)